# Datagridview modifying columns in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

i made a form with a DataGridView that is connected to a SQL table.
in visual studio graphic design i cant see the tables:
[Visual graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE8Zt.png)
but when i execute the program i see the columns because it loads them in the datagridview, [executed program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbSeT.png)
is there a way i can modify the widht, text color.. etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can programmatically set grid view.

```
            datagridviewname.Columns["Columnname"].Visible = false;
            datagridviewname.Columns["Columnname"].HeaderText = "ColumnnameYouwant";
            datagridviewname.Columns["Columnname"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```